# curve modifier behaving unexpectedly

Tags: bezier-curves, curve-modifier

These are in top orthographic view and wireframe. the object is just an elongated default cube with a reasonable number of loop cuts along it.

I'm trying to make the object follow the exact curvature of the Bezier curve, but it ends up at an angle to it for some reason. (I know it's not because of the wrong axis because I've tried all three and the other two are even further away from the result I want.)

The origin of both the object and the curve are at World Origin where they're joined.

[image: before adding the curve modifier]
[image: after adding the curve modifier]

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here, as this appears to work sometimes but not consistently.

Comment: please provide blend file. did you apply scale & rotation?

Comment: thank you, I tried resetting the rotation and it worked better

Comment: you are welcome